# Parse commandline options other than argparse

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I normally use argparse for parsing arguments,but it looks like its introduced since 2.7,am currently on 2.6.5,I cant upgrade to newer due to company policy,i need someinputs on how else can I parse the options given below,is there an easier and quick way to convert to below to parse options for 2.6.5?please suggest

```
import os
import sys, getopt
import argparse

def main ():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test script')
    parser.add_argument('-sau','--set',action='store',dest='set',help='<Required> Set flag',required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-bg','--base_g',action='store',dest='base_g',help='<Required> Base g',required=True)
    results = parser.parse_args()# collect cmd line args
    set = results.set
    base_g = results.base_g

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argparse` has replaced [**`optparse`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#module-optparse) since version 2.7.

Therefore, use [**`optparse`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#module-optparse).

Comment: @user1927233: you could also install [`argparse` on Python 2.6](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse/): `pip install argparse`.

Comment: @Sebastian - i keep getting the error "Unknown or unsupported command 'install"

Comment: @Sebastian - nevermind,after running sudo apt-get remove pip
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip and then running pip worked

Comment: @Sebastian - one question .how do I restrict the values of the options..lets say in the above case.."sau" option should take only number "0" or "1" and "bg" option should take only integer,how can Implement this?

Comment: @user1927233: you could use `choice` and `type` parameters. Skim through the docs http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html to see what is there.

Answer (score 1):

I also love `argparse` and built-in modules in general. However, when it comes to CL-args parsing, I've come to like [docopt](http://docopt.org/). Since you just include it alongside your source files, you no longer need to worry about deprecated modules. The current source code at GitHub is in Python3 though but tweaking it for Python 2.x shouldn't be too much work.